# Use reflection to to see if Controller is within an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, controller

How do use reflection to determine whether a Controller of a given type is within a Area in an ASP.net MVC project?

I am trying to write a new ControllerTypeResolver for an MvcSiteMap and need to work out if the type I am resolving exists within an Area in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?  As long as you have criteria such as a namespace or a convention based controller name then this is possible.